# Convert an Object to a different type, including Lists of the Object

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a problem with an object. Actually i have to convert an object into another object. Here in my Category object contains a list of categories (subcategories). The main issues in this code is we have to convert the all subcategories (Category objects) into CatgoryUI.

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("In main");
        TestMain tm = new TestMain();
        List<Category> categories= tm.prepareList();
        tm.displayCategories(categories);
        List<CategoryUI> categoryList = tm.convertCategories(categories);
        System.out.println("------Converted------");
        tm.displayConvertedCategories(categoryList);
    }

    private List<Category> prepareList(){
        //Category category = new Category();
        List<Category> level3List1 = new ArrayList<Category>();

        level3List1.add(new Category(4L, "Sentence Equalence", new ArrayList<Category>()));
        level3List1.add(new Category(5L, "Antonyms", new ArrayList<Category>()));
        level3List1.add(new Category(6L, "Text Completion", new ArrayList<Category>()));

        List<Category> level3List2 = new ArrayList<Category>();
        level3List2.add(new Category(7L, "Problem Solving", new ArrayList<Category>()));
        level3List2.add(new Category(8L, "Logical Reasoning", new ArrayList<Category>()));

        List<Category> level2List = new ArrayList<Category>();
        level2List.add(new Category(2L, "Verbal", level3List1));
        level2List.add(new Category(3L, "Quantative", level3List2));

        List<Category> level1List = new ArrayList<Category>();
        level1List.add(new Category(1L, "GRE", level2List));

        return level1List;

    }

    private void displayCategories(List<Category> categories){
        System.out.println("<ul>");
        for(Category category : categories){
            System.out.println("<li>");
            System.out.println(category.getName());
            System.out.println("</li>");
            if(category.getSubCategory().size()>0){
                displayCategories(category.getSubCategory());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("</ul>");
    }
}

package net.sankhya.debug;

import java.util.List;

public class Category {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Category> subCategory;



    public Category(Long id, String name, List<Category> subCategory) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.subCategory = subCategory;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Category> getSubCategory() {
        return subCategory;
    }
    public void setSubCategory(List<Category> subCategory) {
        this.subCategory = subCategory;
    }
}

package net.sankhya.debug;

import java.util.List;

public class CategoryUI {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<CategoryUI> subCategory;

    public CategoryUI(){

    }

    public CategoryUI(Long id, String name, List<CategoryUI> subCategory) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.subCategory = subCategory;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<CategoryUI> getSubCategory() {
        return subCategory;
    }
    public void setSubCategory(List<CategoryUI> subCategory) {
        this.subCategory = subCategory;
    }
}
```

When you display the category list with in ul and li in html view it will display like below. And after converting into CategoryUI object if print the list it should also this play in the same way. So, can any please give any suggestions that how to convert the Category into CategoryUI.

```
<ul>
<li>GRE</li>
<ul>
    <li>Verbal</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Sentence Equalence</li>
        <li>Antonyms</li>
        <li>Text Completion</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Quantative</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Problem Solving</li>
        <li>Logical Reasoning</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: My question has nothingto do with your problem but why don't you make CategoryUI and Category implement the same interface?

Comment: I agree @C.Champagne, that would be the correct approach. My answer is based on the assumption that this isn't possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own conversion methods, something like this...

```
public List<CategoryUI> convertArray(List<Category> categoryArray){
    List<CategoryUI> convertedArray = new ArrayList<CategoryUI>();

    for (int i=0;i<categoryArray.size();i++){
        convertedArray.add(convertObject(categoryArray.get(i)));
    }

    return convertedArray;
}


public CategoryUI convertObject(Category category){
    return new CategoryUI(category.getId(),category.getName(),convertArray(category.getSubCategory()));
}
```

Just call `convertObject(category)` for each object that you want to convert. You affectively create a new object of the correct type, and populate it with all the data from the old object. It also converts the array of subCategories. If you pass in the top node of your tree, the one call will work through all the sub-categories of the tree and convert all of them, so its nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) if you need to do it more often in you application
It will perform the mapping automatically.